# Not able to display constant in HTML

Tags: angular, constants

I have constant file with contact inform (Array of object)below as the example to display in HTML page

```
export const CONTACT US
contactDetails: [
「
header: 'Customer Service', description: '1-877-743-3215*
Its
10
11
header: 'Hours of Operation'
description: ‘teet’]
```

Trying to display HTML but it says unavailable

HTML

```
<div "ngFor-*let contact of contactUs.contactDetails",
‹div>test‹/div> (span>1-8778743-3215</span>
‹div›Hours of operation‹/div›
«span›Monday-Friday: 8 a.m. -6 p.m. CT</span›
```

Component file below

```
ngonInit
this.contactUs =CONTACT_US;
```

Comment: please format you question so is readable.

Answer (score 0):

See [interpolation](https://angular.io/guide/interpolation)

```
<div *ngFor="let contact of contactUs.contactDetails",
‹div>test‹/div> {{contact.description}}</span>
</div>
```

But it's possible to need transform your array in some like

```
this.contactUs =CONTACT_US.map((x:any)=>{
   const values=x.description.split('/n')
   return {
           header:x.header,
           phone:values[0],
           description:values[5].split(':')[1]
           ...
   }
});
```

NOTE: I suggest you try the [tour of heroes](https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes) tutorial to take a good aproach to Angular